# How can I check PayPal IPN on sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Hi i need to redirect on mysite after paypal  checkout, i know how to do this as i have read and seen on paypal developer guide but i can't found any feature in paypal sandbox that could redirect to my site AUTOMATICALLY. 
thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide more details, i believe that automatic redirect is already enabled by default in ipn

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might be a little confused between IPN and "Automatic Return / Payment Data Transfer"

**IPN (Instant Payment Notification)**

PayPal sends a message over HTTP protocol to your server when a payment has been made (or updated).  This happens asynchronously - completely divorced from the user flow.

**Automatic Return**

By logging in to your seller account and then visiting Profile -> Hosted Payment Settings -> Website Payment Preferences you can enable Auto Return.  This is the setting that tells PayPal to send the user back to your site after completing their transaction on PayPal.com.

NOTE - no matter what you do, this setting does *NOT* apply to users who make a straight up credit card payment on PayPal.  (E.g. The user does not have a PayPal account.)

**Payment Data Transfer**

This is an optional addition to Automatic Return.  If enabled, PayPal will send some useful information along in the URL that goes to your site.  (Including the PayPal transaction id.)

Comment: thanks cailinanne ya i was confused about ipn and automatic return, here i'm trying to make an appointment scheduler and trying to figure it out how to insert data into my database after successful payment. 

I tried to pass secession variable but there is no guarantee that user will click on "return to home" url after payment where i wanted to run query and insert it into my database.

Please guide me how can we do so. :)